# MySQL optimised code for 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables,

Table1: id,int1,int2,int3,int4,int5

Table2: integers (autoincrement),blobdata

The query I want to use is given the id I want to get the blobdata from table2 associated with the 5 integers in table1.  I've only ever used one table in mysql so have no idea how to do this properly.

Is it possible?

EDIT: id is username, integers in table2 is just integers.  but have not built the tables yet, so can change if need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> select t1.id, t1.int1, t1.int2 ... t2.blobdata
> from table1 t1, table2 t2 
> where t1.id = t2.id and t1.id = <your input id>
> ```

Assuming the auto increment integer column is the id that match the id on table1.

t2.id - or any other name you will call this column of course.

Comment: edited original, sorry.  table 2 has just integers as autoincrement unrelated to the id in table1, which is username.  could this still work?

Comment: You must set a foreign key - that connects the two tables in order to have a meaning to your question: "associates with..." the "where" clause will set the association terms, it can be anything.(there are other ways to write it, using join clause, but this is basic - in order to get the right row from table2 you need to supply the 'key'...

Comment: I don't think you understand what foreign key means. if a row in table1 is associates to a row in table 2 (by it's id) than the column int1 for example should hold that id. and then you will write "Where t1.int1 = t2.id and t1.id = <your input id> " in the where clause

Comment: Watching a youtube video on foreign keys now, thanks.  Do I set int1 up to int5 as foreign keys and then integers in table2 as foreign key too?

Comment: you need only one foreign key - if item 1 in t1 is associate to item 12 on t2, you need to store the number 12 on t1 - this is one column unless you have more than one item on t2 that is associated to one item on t1

Comment: but if there are 5 integers, one in each int column of table1, then those integers link to the first column of table2, so is it 5 foreign keys in my example?

Comment: You should study a little about data models, ERD, SQL before you proceed. it will make things clearer.

Comment: if you have up to 5 object on table 2 that associates with 1 object on table1 than you have 5 foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set a foreign key in table1, which would contain the id of the blobdata you want to point to.

Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: To do as you say, do I set int1 up to int5 as foreign keys in table1, and integers as a foreign key in table2??

Comment: No, you should a blobdata_id foreign key in your table1. And whenever you want to link table 1 datas to a specific table2 row, you just have to fulfil the foreign key field.